# Is there a way to check if my custom service is running or not through adb?

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line, adb

I have checked over the internet and on the stackoverflow also but can't find a solution for this..Is this Possible Using ADB?

Comment: did you try [this link](http://www.akamaras.com/linux/linux-script-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-and-start-it-if-its-stopped/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check whether your custom service is running or not by below adb command.

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services <your-package-name>
```

It will give all your running service info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell command to check if your application is running.

**`ps | grep com.yourpackage`**

To check if your service is running.

**`ps | grep service`**

And to get the running service list for your package,

**`service list | grep com.yourpackage`**

ADB command:

> adb shell service list | grep com.yourpackage